# Extremely strange iTunesConnect error--Missing Screenshot?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, submission

So I finally got through the mess of preparing my app binary to support the iPad, making it a univeral app, and then I got this strange error "Missing Screenshot". And due to the fact that I hadn't uploaded my iPad screenshots to the original binary (I forgot) that error made sense. So I went into the original iPhone app, added my iPad screenshots, and hoped that somehow it would just work, but it didn't.

So then, I rejected the binary, and made sure the iPad screenshots were where they needed to be, re-uploaded a new binary, and it still says MISSING SCREENSHOT. I emailed apple, and they characteristically won't get back to me till probably sometime next week, so I am hoping that someone here can shed some on this error for me! What can I do to get that error to go away, so I can get my ap reviewed and updated? Thank you very much!

Comment: This is more of an issue with Apple's iTunes Connect site, so rather than ask here, I'd suggest asking at https://devforums.apple.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set screenshots for all of the locales you are posting your app in

Comment: @Steve - You aren't stupid.  Apple is stupid for not validating those requirements before letting the app enter the submission queue.

Comment: I got caught by this, turned out when I was changing my version no. to 1.0, i accidently changed the app to a universal app, and it was complaining because I had no iPad screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

After you upload the screenshots for the new supported device type through iTunesConnect, the state will /should/ automatically change back to "Wait for review".